# Repeating Swift timer gives SIGABRT error

Tags: swift, timer, sigabrt

I am trying to make a repeating timer that will go off every second in the background in Swift, but once I run the code, it comes back SIGABRT.

```
var CAPS = 0

let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(CAPSTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func CAPSTimer() {
    let closedAdds = Int(closedAddsCounter.text!)!
    var CAPSAddOne = closedAdds + CAPS
    closedAddsCounter.text = "\(CAPSAddOne)"
}
```

I've tried to change the code, but the only other one that works doesn't repeat.

Comment: Do you have an error message in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this lines

```
var CAPS = 0
var CAPSAddOne = 0
var closedAdds = 0
override func viewDidLoad()
{
   let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(CAPSTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   closedAdds = Int(closedAddsCounter.text!)!
   CAPSAddOne = closedAdds
}

@objc func CAPSTimer() {
    CAPSAddOne += CAPS
    closedAddsCounter.text = "\(CAPSAddOne)"
}
```

Comment: It works, but a new problem has arisen. The closed adds count always goes back to 0.

Comment: I suppose that your label has a initial value, or how do you load the data in your label? and the var CAPS in your question is zero, how do you change his value?

Comment: I change the CAPS value by having 10 closed adds, and buying a "Add Popper" which increases the CAPS by 1. I tested it by changing the caps value to one, and it fixed the problem

Comment: Fixed it using IF statement!

Answer (score 1):

A very common cause of “Signal SIGABRT” is a typo or bug in your outlets.
I see that you have a some unwrapped values in your code for getting the closedAdsCount.

Try to check your closedAddsCounter IBOutlet too see if there is not a missing link

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to **read** the value from the label.

Just use one property and create a strong reference to the timer.

And it's always recommended to dispatch code in an target/action method to the main thread

```
var counter = 0

var timer : Timer!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
   timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(CAPSTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   closedAddsCounter.text = "\(counter)"
}

@objc func CAPSTimer() {
    counter += 1 
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.closedAddsCounter.text = "\(self.counter)"
    }
}
```

Or with the (more contemporary) block based API (delete the action method)

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
   timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in    
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.counter += 1 
          self.closedAddsCounter.text = "\(self.counter)"
       }
   }
   closedAddsCounter.text = "\(counter)"
}
```

If the code still crashes then the outlet is not connected.